Is this a valid criterion for Bochner integrability?
Let $X$ be a measure space and $V$ a Banach space. If we have a function $f: \ X \to V$ and a sequence of Bochner-integrable functions $f_n: \ X \to V$ such that $$
\int_X ||f_n(x) - f(x)|| \ dx \ \rightarrow 0$$ as $n$ goes to infinity, does it follow that $f$ is also Bochner-integrable?
This seems to make sense, since what is happening here is almost similar to the definition of Bochner-integrability through simple functions.

Yes, at least if $f$ is strongly measurable.
For each $n$, let $g_n$ be a simple function such that $\int\|g_n-f_n\|\mathrm d x< 1/n$. Let $\epsilon>0$. For $n$ large enough, $\int\|f_n-f\|\mathrm d x<\epsilon/2$ and $1/n<\epsilon/2$. Therefore,
$$\int\|g_n-f\|\mathrm d x\leq \int\|g_n-f_n+f_n-f\|\mathrm d x\leq \int\|g_n-f_n\|\mathrm d x+\int\|f_n-f\|\mathrm d x<\epsilon.$$
